# Viewing the MSDN documentation of a framework type in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Is it possible in Visual Studio 2010 to be able to right-click on a framework class such as System.Web.UI.Page in my code and be able to click to view the documentation for that class?

Comment: I think by default if you hit `F1` it will work. It is sure configurable by the `Tools` on VS

Comment: close enough for me, thanks.  Move your comment to an answer and I'll mark it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Select the framework class and hit `F1`, it will open the MSDN.